# Swift 3 - Save Firebase Data In Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, viewcontroller

I am trying to save my Firebase Data in an array but the array count is everytime 0.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        getAllSkateShops()
}


func getAllSkateShops() {

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("Shops").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            //var newShops: [SkateShop] = []

            for item in snapshot.children {

                let skateShopItem = SkateShop(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                self.shops.append(skateShopItem)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                  print("OBSERVE SHOP COUNT: \(self.shops.count)")
                })
            }

        })
}
```

And in the function viewDidLoad() is self.shop.count is zero but I need this array with all Shops.

I hope anybody can help me ;)

Comment: I solve the problem with a little hack! I take a tableViewController

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, idk why this works but in DispatchQueue.main.async do (edited):

```
func getAllSkateShops() {

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("Shops").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //var newShops: [SkateShop] = []

        for item in snapshot.children {

            let skateShopItem = SkateShop(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            self.shops.append(skateShopItem)
            self.shops2.append(skateShopItem)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                var temporaryArray = self.shop2
                self.shop = temporaryArray
            })
        }

    })
}
```

If that doesn't work comment, I'll give another option that might work.

Comment: @MartinZagar Ok try now.

Comment: @martin and don't forget to create another variable shops2

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work again, but I read something about the threads at Apple and the reason why it doesn't work, is that first off the I/O is on the main thread and then all callback functions are on the main thread; or like that!